# Exclude kernel modules from plain Buildroot 2016.05 image

Tags: linux, buildroot

Buildroot is a great tool for creating a custom embedded linux system. If one builds a plain system without any changes from the default configuration using the current 2016.05 version one ends up with a modest size image.

The rootfs has a size of 44.3 MB. The directory `/lib/modules/4.4.8/kernel` has a size of 41.4 MB.

I guess that not all this modules are needed. Is there any way to omit unnecessary modules and shrink the image therefore?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple: remove the directory with the modules (or any subset) from `output/target/lib` and execute another `make` to rebuild the image file. The files are omitted and the image is smaller.

In order to reduce the image size further one can shrink the `boot.vfat` file which contains the boot partition. The size can be adjusted in `nano board/YOUR_BOARD/genimage-YOUR_BOARD.cfg`.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.